# Map-like array function in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there something like a `map` function in Excel?

For example, let's say I want to apply the formula `ABS` to a list of items. Something like:

```
=ABS,{-1,2,3,4,5}
```

As an example of python-like notation:

```
# list comprehension
>>> [abs(i) for i in [-1,2,3,4,5]]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# map
>>> map(abs,[-1,2,3,4,5])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# passing arbitrary function
>>> map(lambda x:abs(x)+1, [-1,2,4,5,6])
[2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
```

Is there something similar in Excel?

---

Note, the closest I've gotten is using native operators against lists, such as `=2*{1,2,3,4,5}`, but this just gives things like the basic arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ***Excel-365*** you can directly use `ABS()` function with array of data. Try-

```
=ABS({-1,2,3,4,5})
```

[image]

Comment: very cool, thank you. Do most functions support that? Or just some of them.

Comment: Maximum number of function support this but depends on data operation.

Comment: @David542 Excel is tricky sometimes. There are some exception such as `EOMONTH(A1:A5,1)` returns `#VALUE`, but it works converting the input into array: `EOMONTH(+A1:A5,1)` and it works using directly an array: `EOMONTH({1;2},1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`MAP`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/map-function-48006093-f97c-47c1-bfcc-749263bb1f01) function in Excel with a similar notation to other languages. Note however, that you must pass it a [`LAMBDA`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) function, not just an in-line formula. Here then would be your answer:

```
=MAP({-1,2,3,4,5},LAMBDA(x, ABS(x)))
```

[image]

Comment: Useful for those few Excel functions that don't support array inputs (eg `LCM`)